# form input doesn't get sent into the data base

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm trying to make an archive website for a school project, and while I followed a bunch of different tutorials it seems like something is just not clicking, because nothing gets added to the database (ALTHOUGH files get added to the file they're supposed to go to).

Here's the code that's supposed to link the input page to the database:

```
<?php

    include ('config.php');

    if(isset($_POST['upload']))
    {
    $TITLE= $_POST['title'];
    $NAMES= $_POST['names'];
    $DESCRIPTION= $_POST['description'];
    $FILE= $_FILES ['file'];
    $file_location = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
    $file_name = $_FILES['file']['name'];
    $file_up   = "files/".$file_name;
    $insert = "INSERT INTO projects ('title', 'names', 'description', 'file') VALUES('$TITLE', '$NAMES', '$DESCRIPTION', '$file_up')";

    if(move_uploaded_file($file_location, './files/'.$file_name))
    {
        echo "<script>alert('تمت إضافة المشروع بنجاح!') </script>";

    } 
    else{
        echo "<script>alert('جرب مرة أخرى') </script>";

    } 
    header('location: archive.php');
    }

    ?>
```

**the config.php code:**

```
<?php
$servername= 'sql211.infinityfree.com';
$username= 'if0_36063631';
$password= 'zm4UGYGlSxhNB';
$database= 'if0_36063631_projects';


$conn=new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $database);
?>
```

If anyone figures the problem out please explain it in simple terms

Comment: You've declared the sql query but you haven't actually executed it

Comment: Also not sure what tutorials you're following but they aren't teaching you to build your queries correctly. To keep them secure and reliable when including user input in them, you need to use prepared statements and parameters. Take a look at https://phpdelusions.net/mysqli which shows you properly how to do everything with mysqli